# Distributed mode not working with concurrent calls. | OrientDB v3.0.4

Tags: orientdb

### Use case

`Blueprints implementation` of orient graph should be able to connect to cluster and create vertices and edges on the graph `concurrently` (In our case there are `16 threads` each with its `own graph instance` modifying the graph) . Client app is handling ONeedRetryException and all the server/client side configuration is unmodified. Moreover, it works `fine` with `OrientDB v2.2.35`.

### Actual behavior

Three server nodes are able to join cluster and talk to each other (sync databases) but client throws a exception while creating graph.

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedRecordLockedException: Timeout (0ms) on acquiring lock on record #-1:-1 on server 'DeadLock'. It is locked by request 2.1301
    DB name="apmnew1"
    DB name="apmnew1"
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor67.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.throwSerializedException(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:318) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.handleStatus(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:275) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:191) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:153) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1812) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.lambda$networkOperationRetryTimeout$2(OStorageRemote.java:226) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:285) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperationRetryTimeout(OStorageRemote.java:214) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperationNoRetry(OStorageRemote.java:239) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.commit(OStorageRemote.java:997) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.internalCommit(ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.java:2744) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:534) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:100) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.commit(ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.java:2232) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.commit(ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.java:2202) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:734) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.commit(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:184) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
```